# python script error when writing to another file

Tags: python, file

i am trying to write a python script to get all the content in one file to be written to another file . but i am getting the below error . the code i am using is :

```
#!/user/bin/env python

with open('log.txt', 'r') as file:

line = file.read()

with open('/etc/snort/rules/test.rules' , 'w') as f2:

f2.write(line)
```

the error i get is :

in line 7

```
with open('/etc/snort/rules/test.rules' , 'w') as f2:

***IndentationError : expected an indented block***
```

Comment: Python is indentation sensitive, everythng in your with statement should have a one-level indentation

Comment: Then you should indent the line `f2.write(line)` as well as `line = file.read()`. Indentation is usually 4 spaces per level of  (Hint: if a line ends in a colon `:`, then at least one line underneath it needs to be indented).

Comment: Hi , i am new in using python , i am not sure what should i do to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/user/bin/env python

with open('log.txt', 'r') as file:
    line = file.read()
#### <-- the line above has 4 spaces worth of indentation.  
with open('/etc/snort/rules/test.rules' , 'w') as f2:
    f2.write(line)
```

I indented the lines under the 'with' statements by 4 spaces

Comment: @Sara mark this answer as correct if it has solved your issue. It makes the solution clearer to others and gives @N Chauhan credit for helping. Thanks :)